# how to adjust spark execuator PermGen parameter using cloudera manager?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, cloudera-manager

When I tried to run random forest in Spark on Yarn cluster (3 data nodes). I met **OutOfMemoryError exception**.

The following is the error stack on **container log on node manager**

### OutOfMemoryError exception log

`16/05/30 13:41:17 WARN yarn.YarnAllocator: Expected to find pending requests, but found none.
Exception in thread "dispatcher-event-loop-4" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.defineClass(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.ClassDefiner.defineClass(ClassDefiner.java:63)
    at sun.reflect.MethodAccessorGenerator$1.run(MethodAccessorGenerator.java:399)
    at sun.reflect.MethodAccessorGenerator$1.run(MethodAccessorGenerator.java:396)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.MethodAccessorGenerator.generate(MethodAccessorGenerator.java:395)
    at sun.reflect.MethodAccessorGenerator.generateSerializationConstructor(MethodAccessorGenerator.java:113)
    at sun.reflect.ReflectionFactory.newConstructorForSerialization(ReflectionFactory.java:331)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.getSerializableConstructor(ObjectStreamClass.java:1376)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.access$1500(ObjectStreamClass.java:72)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$2.run(ObjectStreamClass.java:493)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$2.run(ObjectStreamClass.java:468)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.<init>(ObjectStreamClass.java:468)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.lookup(ObjectStreamClass.java:365)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.<init>(ObjectStreamClass.java:464)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.lookup(ObjectStreamClass.java:365)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1133)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1547)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1508)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1431)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1177)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:347)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializationStream.writeObject(JavaSerializer.scala:44)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.serialize(JavaSerializer.scala:101)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.serialize(NettyRpcEnv.scala:251)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.ask(NettyRpcEnv.scala:228)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEndpointRef.ask(NettyRpcEnv.scala:509)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEndpointRef.ask(RpcEndpointRef.scala:62)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManagerMasterEndpoint$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$storage$BlockManagerMasterEndpoint$$removeRdd$2.apply(BlockManagerMasterEndpoint.scala:147)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManagerMasterEndpoint$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$storage$BlockManagerMasterEndpoint$$removeRdd$2.apply(BlockManagerMasterEndpoint.scala:146)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
16/05/30 13:41:21 INFO yarn.YarnAllocator: Canceling requests for 0 executor containers`

### configuration from the log

`LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/native:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH" {{JAVA_HOME}}/bin/java -server -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError='kill %p' -Xms1024m -Xmx1024m -Djava.io.tmpdir={{PWD}}/tmp '-Dspark.authenticate=false' '-Dspark.shuffle.service.port=7337' '-Dspark.driver.port=34896' '-Dspark.ui.port=0' -Dspark.yarn.app.container.log.dir=<LOG_DIR> -XX:MaxPermSize=256m org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend --driver-url spark://CoarseGrainedScheduler@172.26.34.93:34896 --executor-id 2 --hostname datalake01 --cores 1 --app-id application_1464237978069_0248 --user-class-path file:$PWD/__app__.jar --user-class-path file:$PWD/com.databricks_spark-csv_2.11-1.4.0.jar --user-class-path file:$PWD/org.apache.commons_commons-csv-1.1.jar --user-class-path file:$PWD/com.univocity_univocity-parsers-1.5.1.jar 1> <LOG_DIR>/stdout 2> <LOG_DIR>/stderr`

### how to adjust the PermGen size?

This `-XX:MaxPermSize=256m` is the parameter what I want to adjust. But how to adjust this parameter in Cloudera Manager?

Answer (score 3):

You can add the JVM parameters to the spark-submit command.
It is important to note, that you have configuration for the driver and for the executors.

```
spark/bin/spark-submit ... --conf spark.driver.extraJavaOptions=" -XX:MaxPermSize=256M " --conf spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=" -XX:MaxPermSize=256M " ...
```